# Oracle sql developer - Auto clean 'script output' on every execution

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In the worksheet, each time command is executed, it's output is added to "script output" page.
But the result from last executions is not cleared and it is very confusing.
Is there any way to auto clear all other outputs except the last one (instead clear manually each time)?

I did searched for solution but didn't find anything I can try.

Thanks

Attached the screens after first command and second command

**First run:**

[image]

**Second run:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there's no such option. If you go to "Preferences" and search the whole list, there's nothing like that in there. Or, at least, I don't know it.

What you could do is to **type**

```
clear screen
```

(or even shorter, `cl scr`) in Worksheet.

**Or**, if you type fast and don't make much mistakes, press combination of

- `Alt + PgDn` to navigate to script output
- `Ctrl + Shift + D` to clear contents
- `Alt + PgUp` to return up

**Or**, simply push the *eraser* icon in the toolbar.

Comment: yup, it's what i do, i just add 'Clear Screen' to the top of my scripts...automatically nuking script output would inevitably bite people when they weren't expecting it

Comment: Right; I like to have it for *history* purposes. How would I review it if it is automatically gone? Though, if there was an option to switch it on or off ... maybe it would help someone.